# Polymer-CLI: $ polymer build ... Unable to uglify file ... bower_components/**/*

Tags: javascript, polymer, windows-10, git-bash, polymer-cli

Here's my setup...

---

**OS:** Windows 10 (64-bit)
**Git SCM:** 2.7.0 (MINGW64)
**Node:** 6.3.0
**Polymer-CLI:** 0.12.0

---

```
Oneeezy@Oneezy MINGW64 ~/Desktop/www_/_clients/diesel/wwwSFI (default)
$ polymer build

info:    Building application...
info:    Generating build/unbundled...
info:    Generating build/bundled...

warn:    Unable to uglify file C:\Users\Oneeezy\Desktop\www_\_clients\diesel\wwwSFI\bower_components\marked-element\demo\index.html_script_0.js
warn:    Unable to uglify file C:\Users\Oneeezy\Desktop\www_\_clients\diesel\wwwSFI\bower_components\marked-element\test\marked-element.html_script_0.js
warn:    Unable to uglify file C:\Users\Oneeezy\Desktop\www_\_clients\diesel\wwwSFI\bower_components\marked-element\test\marked-element.html_script_1.js
warn:    Unable to uglify file C:\Users\Oneeezy\Desktop\www_\_clients\diesel\wwwSFI\bower_components\marked-element\test\marked-element.html_script_2.js
warn:    Unable to uglify file C:\Users\Oneeezy\Desktop\www_\_clients\diesel\wwwSFI\bower_components\marked-element\test\marked-element.html_script_3.js
warn:    Unable to uglify file C:\Users\Oneeezy\Desktop\www_\_clients\diesel\wwwSFI\bower_components\marked-element\test\marked-element.html_script_4.js
warn:    Unable to uglify file C:\Users\Oneeezy\Desktop\www_\_clients\diesel\wwwSFI\bower_components\web-component-tester\data\index.html_script_0.js
warn:    Unable to uglify file C:\Users\Oneeezy\Desktop\www_\_clients\diesel\wwwSFI\bower_components\web-component-tester\data\index.html_script_2.js

info:    Generating service workers...
info:    Build complete!

Oneeezy@Oneezy MINGW64 ~/Desktop/www_/_clients/diesel/wwwSFI (default)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
polymer build --verbose
```

to see what the error is